# Creating date fields in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, date

I am trying to create a month and a day column in ArcGIS Pro 2.8. For values I just want to have "01" and "01" for month and day respectively. So, I have 1032 rows, thus "01" and "01" will be filled in 1032 rows under the month and day column.

Now, I have created two columns with the date format, but when I enter "1" as the month value, I get weird date values.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: There is no "month" or "day" data type for feature classes, there is a `date` type for storing dates and times.  If you want the actual value in the field to be "01", then you will have to make it a text field.  Alternatively, you could store a proper date and format the display, but the values themselves would not be "01", they would just be formatting to look that way.

Comment: Also, see [SQL Reference for query expressions used in ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/help/mapping/navigation/sql-reference-for-elements-used-in-query-expressions.htm).  December 30, 1899 is the epoch for the `date` data type in ArcGIS Pro.  Putting a value of `1` in the Field Calculator effectively told the software to add one day to that date, hence 12/31/1899.